# Identify this frame year and build

Tags: identify-this-bike

I am interested in picking up this frame for a rebuild project. I can't find info on which year this is or what model. Most models seem to have a black rear triangle, presumably carbon.

After sleuthing online, I can't find any that have the website printed on the rear triangle and the specific branding. The forks and stem are obviously a placeholder from another bike. But is the frame okay? It's not a repaint is it? Or, worse, a crappy frame painted and with stickers? What would you estimate the worth is?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet may be to get the serial number and contact orbea.

Comment: Looking for an Orbea Euskaltel on google, i saw several that looked VERY similar, some even had the website, but of those at least one was a replica. So before you pay much for it i would try and research the serial number to see what it really is. My guess would be an 04ish year wise, and it's the Euskaltel team model/colorway.

Comment: If it helps, Euskaltel is the name of the  Basque (region in northern Spain) cycling team. I think Orbea still sponsor them. Orbea  is a Spanish cycling manufacturer.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Orbea Logo was used from around 1995-2004 however in the early 2000s the started changing the rear seat stays and chain stay to be black. the biggest way to know the exact year would be to see the tube shapes. starting in 200 they started going to more of a triangular tube and going away from round and oval. It looks like you have a a 2000-2003 frame. that being said, I highly doubt it is an original team frame, they did make many replicas. That said it doesn't make the frame not as good as an original. These bikes came with DuraAce components, I can't tell what you have on there.